# Como puedo implementar una librería de terceros a laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy desarrollando una e-commerce en laravel y necesito implementar una librería o plugin de x banco para el tema de pagos:

- ¿En dónde ubico los archivos?
- ¿Cómo la puedo implementar?

El banco me "entrego" una carpeta con 4 clases PHP (plugin, plugin consultas, consultas y consultas resp), intenté agregarla al vendor y requerirlo en el controlador pero no me funciona.

Básicamente no sé cómo implementar código que no está relacionado con laravel.

Uso laravel 4.5.

Comment: Considera esto: si tú leyeras la pregunta tal cual está podrías responderla?, Para que puedas recibir ayuda checa el enlace que te di, además procura proveer un ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable además de los errores obtenidos al momento

Comment: Revisa en packagist (por Google) si tienes un bundle relacionado con el ecommerce, en el que puedas crear tu propio gestor de ese banco. La mayoría de los sistemas te permiten definir tu operador utilizando sus clases y luego los archivos que te pasan los bancos.

Answer (score 0):

Actualización: ya lo pude resolver, básicamente cree en directorio dentro app y a cada clase de di su respectivo namespace. fuente: https://programacionymas.com/blog/agregar-clases-propias-laravel

Comment: amigo gracias por su opinion, ya le he leido 3 veces y no se a que se refie, perdon por no ser tan crack como uste  "Siempre sé educado y diviértete
Está bien si no estás de acuerdo o si expresas preocupación, pero compórtate bien. Hay un ser humano al otro lado de la pantalla, no importa lo equivocado que parezca. Estamos aquí para aprender de nuestros colegas, no para gritarnos el uno al otro.".